# Conda environment is not activated in snakemake for rules declared as local

Tags: conda, snakemake

I have an issue with Snakemake v5.26.1 and I am not sure whether this is a bug or whether I am doing something wrong.

I have the following rule:

```
rule multiqc:
input:
    expand('results/{project}/fastqc/{sample}/{sample}_R{idx}_fastqc.{ext}', project=PROJECT, sample=SAMPLES, idx=[1,2], ext=['html', 'zip'])
output:
    html = 'results/{project}/fastqc/multiqc_report.html'
params:
    out = lambda wildcards, output: os.path.dirname(output['html'])
conda:
    'envs/multiqc.yaml'
shell:
    'multiqc --force -o {params.out} {params.out}'
```

where `multiqc.yaml` is the specification of a `conda` environment with `multiqc` installed.

When I execute the pipeline locally using, for example, `snakemake --profile profiles/local/` everything works as expected. This is also the case, when I execute the code on the cloud using `tibanna`: `snakemake --profile profiles/aws/`. So far, so good.

The above rule is very lightweight and it makes sense to execute it locally, so I have the declaration `localrules: all, multiqc` somewhere in my `Snakefile` and this is where the problems begin. In this case, when I execute the code in the cloud, it seems that the `conda` environment defined in `multiqc.yaml` is not automatically installed or activated and I get a `command 'multiqc' not found` error. The hack I am currently using to bypass this problem is to install `multiqc` locally, but this solution is ugly and it affects the portability of the pipeline. I suspect I could solve the problem by using a `singularity` image with `multiqc` installed, but still the most elegant solution would be to somehow make the `conda: 'envs/multiqc.yaml'` part of the rule work.

Is the above behaviour expected or is it a bug (either in my code or `snakemake`)? What would be the best solution to resolve this issue (using a `singularity` image, maybe)?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

- For the conda environment to be activated you need to add the option `--use-conda` in snakemake, I.e. `snakemake --use-conda ...`
- Do you really need to execute multiqc in its own conda environment? If you can install and run multiqc locally without clashes with the other snakemake rules, I suspect you don't need a dedicated environment for it.
- If all of the above fails, I would rather run multiqc as a job for the cluster rather than as a local rule to avoid the convoluted solutions you mention.

Comment: Hi Dario,

1) Yes, I use the `--use-conda` flag. This is why the behaviour I observe is weird.
2) I suppose it would be good to have a dedicated `conda` environment for each rule for portability, but I agree that a local installation of `multiqc`, as I do now, is an acceptable solution.
3) Yes, this solution is simple and portable (`conda` works in this case). The downside is that it is relatively costly: initialising an instance on the cloud takes more time than doing the actual job (which is why `localrules: ...` exists).

Thank you very much for your time and thoughtful comments!